# If length of item in Pandas Dataframe = 3 add 'XXX00', if length of item in Pandas Dataframe = 2 add 'XXX000', else do nothing

Tags: python

I have dataframe in Pandas and need to add characters to the ItemNUMBER if the length is less than 4.

Here an example screenshot of the dataframe:
[image: Here a screenshot of the dataframe:]

So ItemNUMBER for items with length of one would have 'XXX00'0 added in front of it so '5' would be 'XXX0005' and ItemNUMBER with length two need XXX00 in front so '10' would be 'XXX0010' and ItemNUMBER with length three needs 'XXX0' in front so '111' would be replaced with 'XXX0111' and ItemNUMBER length four would remain the same.

I have:

```py
lenitem = DF['ItemNUMBER'].str.len()

if lenitem ==1:
    DF['ItemNUMBER'] = 'XXX000' + DF['ItemNUMBER'].astype(str)
elif lenitem ==2:
    DF['ItemNUMBER'] = 'XXX00' + DF['ItemNUMBER'].astype(str)
elif lenitem ==3:
    DF['ItemNUMBER'] = 'XXX0' + DF['ItemNUMBER'].astype(str)
else:
    DF['ItemNUMBER']
```

but get the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The goal output is for ItemNUMBER '4676' to remain the same, ItemNUMBER '5' to = 'XXX0005', and ItemNUMBER '10' to = 'XXX0010'.

How do I fix this and is there a better method to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Remember to use double equal sign: `if lenitem ==1:` instead of `if lenitem =1:` for all your `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you, I still get the same error though.

Comment: you are getting that error because `lenitem` is a Series, not an integer. You would need to make a for loop over the series and then apply your if statement in the for loop. Look at my answer for the way I would go about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a lambda over the column to get your expected outcome.

If column `ItemNUMBER` is a string you can use this;

```
df['nums'].apply(lambda x: 'XXX000'+x if len(x)==1 else 'XXX00'+x if len(x)==2 else'XXX0'+x if len(x)==3 else x)
```

which basically iterates over the entire column and performs that action for each value.

you can think of it being written as such as well;

```
for value in nums:
    if len(x)==1:
        value = 'XXX000'+value 
    elif len(x)==2:
        value = 'XXX00'+value
    elif len(x)==3:
        value = 'XXX0'+value
    else:
        value
```